# How to play two channel wav file with OpenSLES on Android in C++?

Tags: android

I found a [Google Sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/native-audio) that plays 1-channel audio with OpenSLES in C++. If I try to play two-channel wav-file and replace

```
SLDataFormat_PCM format_pcm = {SL_DATAFORMAT_PCM, 1, SL_SAMPLINGRATE_8,
    SL_PCMSAMPLEFORMAT_FIXED_16, SL_PCMSAMPLEFORMAT_FIXED_16,
    SL_SPEAKER_FRONT_CENTER, SL_BYTEORDER_LITTLEENDIAN};
```

with

```
SLDataFormat_PCM format_pcm = {SL_DATAFORMAT_PCM, 2, SL_SAMPLINGRATE_44_1,
    SL_PCMSAMPLEFORMAT_FIXED_16, SL_PCMSAMPLEFORMAT_FIXED_16,
    SL_SPEAKER_FRONT_CENTER, SL_BYTEORDER_LITTLEENDIAN};
```

in the [this C file](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/master/native-audio/app/src/main/cpp/native-audio-jni.c), the app crashes.

Cannot figure out what else should I change? Probably AudioPlayer or OutputMix should be initialized differently for playing different format?

[There is a code](https://github.com/Suvitruf/Android-ndk/blob/master/OpenSLES/jni/OpenSLTest/utils/OSLContext.cpp) that calls CreateOutputMix two times to play 2-channel audio, but it looks a bit strange. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

One problem I see is a comment in the [OpenSLES.h](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenSL-ES/api/1.1/OpenSLES.h) file:

**SLDataFormat_PCM IS DEPRECATED**. Use SLDataFormat_PCM_EX instead.

```
/** PCM-type-based data format definition where formatType must be SL_DATAFORMAT_PCM*/
/* SLDataFormat_PCM IS DEPRECATED. Use SLDataFormat_PCM_EX instead. */
typedef struct SLDataFormat_PCM_ {
    SLuint32         formatType;
    SLuint32         numChannels;
    SLuint32         samplesPerSec;
    SLuint32         bitsPerSample;
    SLuint32         containerSize;
    SLuint32         channelMask;
    SLuint32        endianness;
} SLDataFormat_PCM;

/** PCM-type-based data format definition where formatType must be SL_DATAFORMAT_PCM_EX*/
typedef struct SLDataFormat_PCM_EX_ {
    SLuint32         formatType;
    SLuint32         numChannels;
    SLuint32         sampleRate;
    SLuint32         bitsPerSample;
    SLuint32         containerSize;
    SLuint32         channelMask;
    SLuint32        endianness;
    SLuint32        representation;
} SLDataFormat_PCM_EX;
```

Second issue:

In the file you linked to: android-ndk/native-audio/app/src/main/cpp/[native-audio-jni.c](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/master/native-audio/app/src/main/cpp/native-audio-jni.c)

Line 297:

```
// configure audio source
SLDataLocator_AndroidSimpleBufferQueue loc_bufq = {SL_DATALOCATOR_ANDROIDSIMPLEBUFFERQUEUE, 2};
SLDataFormat_PCM format_pcm = {SL_DATAFORMAT_PCM, 1, SL_SAMPLINGRATE_8,
    SL_PCMSAMPLEFORMAT_FIXED_16, SL_PCMSAMPLEFORMAT_FIXED_16,
    SL_SPEAKER_FRONT_CENTER, SL_BYTEORDER_LITTLEENDIAN};
```

Line 804:

```
// configure audio sink
SLDataLocator_AndroidSimpleBufferQueue loc_bq = {SL_DATALOCATOR_ANDROIDSIMPLEBUFFERQUEUE, 2};
SLDataFormat_PCM format_pcm = {SL_DATAFORMAT_PCM, 1, SL_SAMPLINGRATE_16,
    SL_PCMSAMPLEFORMAT_FIXED_16, SL_PCMSAMPLEFORMAT_FIXED_16,
    SL_SPEAKER_FRONT_CENTER, SL_BYTEORDER_LITTLEENDIAN};
```

You say changing the code to this causes a crash:

```
SLDataFormat_PCM format_pcm = {SL_DATAFORMAT_PCM, 2, SL_SAMPLINGRATE_44_1,
    SL_PCMSAMPLEFORMAT_FIXED_16, SL_PCMSAMPLEFORMAT_FIXED_16,
    SL_SPEAKER_FRONT_CENTER, SL_BYTEORDER_LITTLEENDIAN};
```

Shouldn't you use this instead:

```
SLDataFormat_PCM format_pcm = {SL_DATAFORMAT_PCM, 2 SL_SAMPLINGRATE_44_1,
    SL_PCMSAMPLEFORMAT_FIXED_16, SL_PCMSAMPLEFORMAT_FIXED_16,
    SL_SPEAKER_FRONT_LEFT | SL_SPEAKER_FRONT_RIGHT,
    SL_BYTEORDER_LITTLEENDIAN
};
```

- **Problems:**

  1. Use of deprecated calls which ***might*** not have well debugged code on the unknown device (test on another brand or Emulator).
  2. You ought to use:

```
format_pcm.channelMask = SL_SPEAKER_FRONT_LEFT | SL_SPEAKER_FRONT_RIGHT;
```

References: [Android OpenSL “pAudioSrc: data format 2 not allowed” - denying SL_DATAFORMAT_PCM?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22376081/3648282)

You say; "... the app crashes.". Why not have an error handler pop up a message explaining which error was thrown after the call, after dismissing it the program should simply exit() and not "crash".

PS: I don't have a development environment setup to test your code so I can't be of more help. There are certainly enough sample implementations that have [been improved](https://gist.github.com/hrydgard/3072540) to test against your device. It's certainly more difficult to offer assistance when we don't know which phone or compiler you are using to look for known bugs.

Comment: audio sink is probably for recording, I am changing Line 297. If SLDataFormat_PCM works with 1 channel, it is unlikely that it would not work with 2 channels. By I'll try SLDataFormat_PCM_EX.

Comment: The important point, if you're not a native reader, is after: "Shouldn't you use this instead" ...

Comment: yes, I see. I am still trying and got another error, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52141695/what-is-the-usage-of-sl-datalocator-address-in-opensles-on-android

Comment: There is no SLDataFormat_PCM_EX_ on Android.

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky Some agree with that, [one example](https://github.com/liballeg/allegro5/blob/master/addons/audio/opensl.c) the author says: "Then OpenSL spec says these values are needed for SLDataFormat_PCM_EX
     * but not all implementations define that struct. If they do then
     * the following code can be used.
     */" on line 307. **Also** here [on line 38](https://github.com/wang-bin/QtAV/blob/master/src/output/audio/AudioOutputOpenSL.cpp), **but not here** [line 210](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/wilhelm/+/master/tests/examples/slesTestRecBuffQueue.cpp).